# UITabbar disappears when clicked on a button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I use **UITabBar** in my application. In one of my tabbars, i have a **UITableView** in a **UIViewController** whose root view controller is a **Navigation Controller**. When i click on a cell, i go to my custom edit mode which is a **UIViewController**.

In my edit mode I have a **backButton** that shows me **UIViewController** with the **TableView**.

My problem is when i click **backButton**, my **TabBar** disappears.

Do you have any ideas why my **TabBar** disappears?

Thanks.

Comment: When user click "backButton", you can just popup edit mode view controller so that you can retain the previous page. Did you try it?

Comment: I didn't try that. How can i retain the previous page?

Comment: In back button click, add the following code. [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In back button click, add the following code.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```